# How can I control the SQL table aliases that Hibernate uses in its generated queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

**tl;dr:** Hibernate automatically generates SQL table aliases in its queries like `jurisdicti4_` or `this_`.  Here's an example query:

```
SELECT
    this_.id                            AS id2_6_3_,
    this_.a_table_column                AS a_table_column3_6_3_,
    jurisdicti4_.b_table_column         AS b_table_column4_6_3_,
    
FROM
    app_table_a          this_
    LEFT OUTER JOIN jurisdiction       jurisdicti4_ ON this_.jurisdiction = jurisdicti4_.name
WHERE
    this_.a_table_column = ?
```

I'm using the Hibernate Criteria API to add some hints that need reference the SQL aliases in the query, so I need to know how to either:

1. specify the SQL table aliases Hibernate will use in its queries (e.g. tell it to use `juris` instead of `jurisdicti4_` for `jurisdiction`, or
2. get hibernate to tell me the exact SQL table alias it will use for a particular table or entity (e.g. be told the alias in the query for `jurisdiction` will be `jurisdicti4_`.

---

**Full story:**

I've inherited a Java app with an Oracle DB that uses Hibernate 4.3.8 and the Hibernate Criteria API to generate some complicated search queries.  It recently ran into a severe SQL performance problem that will require us to start to include hints these queries.  However, we use Oracle, and its index hints are in the form of:

`/*+ index (TABLE_ALIAS INDEX_NAME) */`

I've successfully added the needed hints using `Criteria.addHint(...)`, however I've had to hardcode the Hibernate-generated `TABLE_ALIAS` in the hint string.  I'm concerned that over time, the aliases may change, so I want to either control how they're generated or be able to retrieve their values to use when adding the SQL hint.

---

**Edit**: This website describes the Hibernate SQL alias generation process: https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Hibernate/Chapter_23_-_Hibernate_alias_names.jsp

I've found that I have **partial** control of the SQL aliases when I programmatically set up the join like this: `criteria.createAlias(associationPath, alias)`.  The `alias` value I pass seems to be used as the *first part* of the SQL alias for the table.  However, Hibernate appends some kind of generated table ID integer to that, so I'd get something like `myalias4_` in the generated SQL.  Also, this only seems to work in joins I setup myself in the criteria.  Hibernate will often add its own based on the mappings, and I'm not sure how get this same level of partial control over those.